# mapRoute to a Web Form using ASP.NET 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a Url like this

http://localhost:4737/Site/listing/NH/Plaistow/2831516

and I want it to reroute to

http://localhost:4737/Site/listing.aspx

I was reading how to do this for Web Forms here
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx

Here's what my route looks like.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
  "FriendlyUrl",
  "Site/listing/{state}/{town}/{mlsnumber}",
  "~/Site/listing.aspx");
```

In my listing page I plan on accessing the following variables

```
  Page.RouteData.Values["state"]
  Page.RouteData.Values["town"]
  Page.RouteData.Values["mlsnumber"]
```

But when I navigate to http://localhost:4737/Site/listing/NH/Plaistow/2831516, 
I just get a HTTP 404 error.

I know how to get this working with MVC, but this is a fairly large application, all written with web forms, so rewriting isn't feasible.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this would be helpful.

Thanks !

Here is the working code.  Thank you to [mrchief](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244353/mrchief) for helping me resolve this.

```
  routes.MapPageRoute(
  "FriendlyUrl",
  "listing/{state}/{town}/{mlsnumber}", 
  "~/listing.aspx");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yore doing it the other way. If you're using WebForms, you need to implement `UrlRoutingModule` as shown here: https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx

The Routing Rules were designed for use in ASP.Net MVC applications where you redirect a `Url` to its appropriate `Controller` (Page in WebForms) with `action` params (query params in WebFroms parlance).

Comment: That article pertains to .Net Framework 3.5.  I want to do this in 4.0.   This appears in a yellow box on the link you posted.  ASP.NET Routing in ASP.NET 4...  This article explores ASP.NET Routing when used with ASP.NET version 3.5 SP1. The ASP.NET Routing system has been enhanced in ASP.NET version 4 and includes a number of new features that make implementing ASP.NET Routing in a Web Forms application much easier and straightforward. For a look at these new features, check out URL Routing in ASP.NET 4.

Comment: I see... Well you're using `MapRoute` instead of `MapPageRoute`. `MapRoute` is `System.Web.Mvc` extension.

Comment: Thank you sir.  MapPageRoute was one issue.  The other was I needed to remove "Site" from the routeUrl and physicalFile parameters because that was my web application name.